# How to write code for unit testing header in mocha and chai for Node.js express framework application?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing test cases to check with all headers received are correctly spelled or not
suppose there are multiple field names I want to make test cases for all of them that they all are spelled correctly written as in the array of objects. So how I code in mocha and chai

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as it is not clear what your use case is, these are some of the tests I have used before `.to.deep.equalInAnyOrder` will throw an error if the spellings do not match. You have to create test data I am not entirely sure on what you are looking for but the second might be more appropriate.

```
it('200', async () => {

      nock('https://test.ca')

        .get('/test')

        .reply(200, {

          data: 'test',

        });

      const result = await rest.get('test', 'test');

      assert.equal(result.statusCode, 200);

      assert.deepEqual(result.body, { data: 'test' });

      assert.isTrue(nock.isDone());

    });
```

or

you can create an object that has all the results in my case s10

```
it('Get student details', () => {

      return request(app)

        .get('/api/v3/student/10')

        .expect(httpStatus.OK)

        .then(async (res) => {

          expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');

          expect(res.body.career).to.be.an('array');

          expect(res.body.career).to.deep.equalInAnyOrder(s10.career);

        });

    });
```